# Creating variable from chrome.storage.sync.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im building extension which based on user input and saving, will be opening links based on some conditions. Im using chrome.storage.sync.set, everything works fine. I need to create var from data stored by chrome.storage.sync.get. I am storing URLs.

**Storing:**

```
function save_options() {
  var d = document.getElementById('text').value
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    "data": d,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

document.getElementById('set').addEventListener('click',
    save_options);
```

**Retrieving:** This will retrieve stored value and show it on settings page like text, so user knows what data has been stored.

```
function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(items) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
      console.log(items);
      document.getElementById("data").innerText = items.data;
    }
  });
}
```

But when I try to do same thing, retrieve data and create var, Im having only opened empty links:

```
function visit() {
    var f = chrome.storage.sync.get("data");
    window.open(f);
    }
```

Even tried creating global var:

```
var f;
function visit() {
f = chrome.storage.sync.get("data");
window.open(f);
    }
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I just created a monster of an answer on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38456419/934239

Comment: But long story short, the function simply doesn't return anything. Because _reasons_ (see my link above).