# Use result of asynchronous chrome.cookies.getAll

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am running into an asynchronous JavaScript problem, having trouble saving a value received in a callback method as an object literal. I am making a Chrome Extension and using the `chrome.cookies.getAll` method and am able to get the cookies and read them in the callback, but I am not able to save the value to the object. I am still getting the hang of objects and asynchronous JavaScript and could really use some help.

Here's the code

```
var app = {
    init: function() {
        this.activeCookie = {
            'sid': null
        };
        this.setupSession();
        // shows null
        console.log('session in object : ');
        console.log(this.activeCookie['sid']);
    },

    setupSession: function() {
        var that = this;

        function setCookiesAsync(that, cookie) {
            console.log(cookie);
            for(var i=0; i<cookie.length; ++i) {
                if(cookie[i]['name'] === 'sid') {
                    that.activeCookie['sid'] = cookie[i]['value'];
                    // shows a token
                    console.log('session in callback : ');
                    console.log(that.activeCookie['sid']);
                }
            }
        }

        chrome.cookies.getAll({
            'url': ST.BaseUrl
        }, function (cookie) {
            setCookiesAsync(that, cookie);

        });
    }
};
```

Since the callback executes after

```
console.log('session in object : ');
console.log(this.activeCookie['sid']);
```

`this.activeCookie['sid']` is `null`.

I am wondering how I can save the value to the object so the asynchronous method saves it to the object and the subsequent lines of code execute after `setupSession()` is complete.

Comment: Sorry for closing this as a dupe with such a well-crafted question (I upvoted as well), but that's _really_ a common topic.

Comment: yea I know I read a bunch on this, saw some awesome posts on here but still can't save the value to the object.  Can I keep it open?  Can I change it to keep it open?

Comment: Your `init` function is essentially asynchronous as well, since parts of it are - to make sure code executes truly after _everything_ `init` is supposed to do, it needs to take a callback (or return a Promise) that you can guarantee executes after (i.e. at the end of `setCookiesAsync`)

Comment: hmm weird, but thank you.

so i would need something more like:

    var app = {
        init: function(callback) {
            this.activeCookie = {
                'sid': null
            };
            this.setupSession();
    }
};

but what would my callback function look like then, and would it live inside or outside the object?

thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*While this question is on a [very canonical topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron), it's worded and scoped well enough that providing a specific solution as well will be helpful.*

Parts of `init()` are executed asynchronously. What this means is that by the time `init()` finishes executing, not all of its code is yet run. **There is no way around that - code immediately after the async part will run before it.**

However, if you have some code you want to specifically execute after `init` (like, for instance, the rest of your code!), you can do this by passing this code as a callback and adding it to an appropriate place:

```
init: function(callback) {
  this.activeCookie = {
    'sid': null
  };
  this.setupSession(callback);
},

setupSession: function(callback) {
  var that = this;

  function setCookiesAsync(that, cookie) {
    for(var i=0; i<cookie.length; ++i) {
      if(cookie[i]['name'] === 'sid') {
        that.activeCookie['sid'] = cookie[i]['value'];
      }
    }
    // This is the point where all of init() has finished
    if (typeof callback === "function") { callback(); }
  }

  chrome.cookies.getAll({
    'url': ST.BaseUrl
  }, function(cookie) {
    setCookiesAsync(that, cookie);
  });
}
```

Then you can use the code as follows:

```
app.init(function() {
  /* code that should execute after init */
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

```
init: function() {
  this.activeCookie = {
    'sid': null
  };
  return this.setupSession(callback); // returns a Promise
},

setupSession: function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var that = this;

    function setCookiesAsync(that, cookie) {
      for(var i=0; i<cookie.length; ++i) {
        if(cookie[i]['name'] === 'sid') {
          that.activeCookie['sid'] = cookie[i]['value'];
        }
      }
      // This is the point where all of init() has finished
      resolve();
    }

    chrome.cookies.getAll({
      'url': ST.BaseUrl
    }, function (cookie) {
      setCookiesAsync(that, cookie);
    });
  });
}
```

And the usage becomes:

```
app.init().then(function() {
  /* code that should execute after init */
});
```

Comment: You may also want to look at my recent [loooooong answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38456419/934239) on why asynchronous functions are used in Chrome.

Comment: you are awesome than you so much Xan that is really helpful.   I am still working to understand and use the promise implementation, but the callback one makes perfect sense now.  Thank you