# How to use chrome.cookies.getAll asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

**I have tried modifying my code so it looks similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38509312/8242316).**

Hello, my code seems to be returning an empty array when trying to use `chrome.cookies.getAll` asynchronously. It could be that I'm using it incorrectly, or that the `url` isn't passing through.

```
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(HistoryItem) {
    var cookies = {
        start: function(callback) {
            this.logCookies(HistoryItem.url,callback);
        },
        logCookies: function(url,callback) {
            chrome.cookies.getAll({
                'url': url
            }, function(cookie) {
                console.log(cookie) //log the cookie
            });
        }
    }
    cookies.start(function() {
        console.log('getting cookies...')
    });
});
```

I hope this isn't too vague... what I'm trying to do is get all cookies from the currently visited website and log them. *(My hope is to delete them in the future, but for now I would like to log each cookie found)*. Instead, it returns an empty array with the length of 0, and `getting cookies...` does not show up in the console. I'm not sure what I did wrong, it seems to me that I did everything right. I'm new to asynchronous coding, so a little help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of console.log(cookie) use `callback(cookie)`. But I recommend using [Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill). See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried that, and still no luck. It returns an array with the length of 0 still.

Comment: It probably means there were no cookies for that URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for saying that, it reminded me that I needed to add `http` and `https` permissions to my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! Turns out I didn't have the right permissions set in my manifest and I tweaked the code to use `Promises`, and it works completely fine! I got it to remove each cookie, too.

```
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(HistoryItem) {
    var cookies = {

        start: function() {
            return this.logCookies();
        },

        logCookies: function() {

            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

                function remove(cookies){
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        chrome.cookies.remove({url: HistoryItem.url + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name},function(){
                            console.log('cookie removed!')
                        });
                    }
                    resolve()
                }

                chrome.cookies.getAll({
                    'url': HistoryItem.url
                }, function(cookies) {
                    remove(cookies)
                });

            })
        }
    }

    cookies.start().then(function(){
        console.log('removing cookies...')
    });
```

});